# Strange behaviour in iOS Today Widget with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer, today-extension, haptic-feedback

I'm really getting crazy on this, so I'd ask for some help.

I'm coding a little `widget` that presents two `UIButton` the user can tap, once pressed the `widget` adds a notification to the app, if the button is pressed again the notification will be deleted.

Initially I added a sound to the touch of the button and worked ok with `AVPlayer`, then I decided to use the `haptic engine` to give feedback to the user so I deleted the `AVPlayer` call to stop the sound: guess what? the button continues to play the sound! I've commented the code I used to play the sound, **how can it still play the sound?.**

The strange thing is that one button has got this strange behaviour, while the other just works fine (only haptic engine), it sounds like a bug but I'm a rookie and it should be my fault somewhere.

Any idea?